# Some files in "wwwroot" folder are not published in ASP.NET Core web deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017.

My site works fine when I hit debug in [IIS Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#IIS_Express). But when deploying the site to IIS server, not all the folders and files in wwwroot are deployed. I have looked at the .csproj file, but I don't know how to make sure it deploys all files and folders.

Comment: are the file and folders you need part of the .csproj?

Comment: How do you deploy?

Answer (score 23):

It's working for me

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\**">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 18):

I solved the issue. The solution is to edit the .csproj file.

Remove all the `ItemGroup` tags related to wwwroot and then add this one:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The asterisk will include all the subfolders and files.

Comment: all the files in the wwwroot folder will be included except for empty files

Comment: If you remove all the other itemgroup tags, won't other items that were meant to be included end up NOT in the build?

Comment: Why is the element named "None" and not "Content"?

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

```
<PropertyGroup>

<EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: maybe add a short explanation on why you'd do one or both of these things?

Comment: Many project types already include the `wwwroot` folder by default and if you do not use the `<EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>` you will receive a message such as **The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items** when you build the project.

Answer (score 4):

Notice to myself:

when you stumble over this issue again (like it happened twice already), double check whether the `wwwroot` content is really committed to git, and the build agent *has* the files to publish, or if there is an exclusion of `wwwroot` in (any) `.gitignore`

:facepalm: