# ASP.NET Core MVC and static files to the build output directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I didn't work with the MVC a lot and I need a little help with the static files.
However if I build my MVC project and go to the output directory and run the application, all static files are not visible from the browser.

Do I need to copy entire wwwroot folder to the output folder during the build process in order to make static files files accessible. If I need, how can I copy entire wwwroot folder.

[image: browser network]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the _Publish_ command when you are ready to deploy

Comment: Do you mean when you publish the project, `wwwroot` will not be included in output directory? Have you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341844/some-files-in-wwwroot-folder-are-not-published-in-asp-net-core-web-deploy).